# How to build diagonal matrix with list comprehension

Tags: haskell

How can I build an infinite matrix with numbers placed in it diagonally with list comprehension?

```
[[ 1,  2,  4,  7, 11, ...],
 [ 3,  5,  8, 12, 17, ...],
 [ 6,  9, 13, 18, 24, ...], 
 [10, 14, 19, 25, 32, ...],
 ...]
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
firstColumn = take 6 $ map fst $ iterate (\(a,b) -> (a+b,b+1)) (1,2)
matr :: [[Int]]
matr = [take 6 $ map fst $ iterate (\(x,y) -> (x+y, y+1)) (a, i) | a <- firstColumn, let i = 1]
```

But how can I pass (i + 1) to next every row (in other words, how do I iterate for additional rows)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to do the math side of it, or do you need help with that as well? Is this homework?

Comment: And, why does it have to be using a list comprehension?

Comment: it is a part of homework, I've tryed some things this comprehension, so want to now how to do it with comprehension) I think that using other things could be much easier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By finding a formula for the x and y indices, f.e.:

```
[[ 1 + (x + y) * (x + y + 1) `div` 2 + y | x <- [0..]] | y <- [0..]]
```